# SQL Server-Conditional Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, conditional-statements

I have two tables that I want to conditionally join.

Basically, when the `Type` column from table A `='First'` then table A should join to table B on `a.ID = b.ID COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS`, but when the `Type` column from table A `='Second'` then table A should join to table B on `a.Name = b.Name`.

I am putting dummy data below so that you can get a sense of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You can use `or`ed conditions:

```
select a.*, b.amount
from tablea a
inner join tableb b
    on (a.type = 'First'  and b.id   = a.id)
    or (a.type = 'Second' and b.name = a.name)
```